# Force xslt to generate the "xml" domain name

Tags: xml, xslt, attributes, xml-namespaces

I need xslt version 2 to generate the domain name for the "xml" attribute prefix (xml:lang="en-us") at either at the record or element level:

```
xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
```

I tried using both xsl:namespace and using xsl:attribute ... namespace=

Neither worked for me - any suggestions would be terrific
Thanks David

Comment: Its called an xml namespace, not a domian

Answer (score 3):

According to http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#ns-decl "The prefix `xml` is by definition bound to the namespace name `http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace`. It MAY, but need not, be declared, and MUST NOT be bound to any other namespace name." so while you can certainly use that namespace on a literal result element or output it with `xsl:namespace` I think there is no guarantee that the serializer outputs it as omitting it does not change the semantics of the XML.

Answer (score 2):

As Martin has already explained, the prefix `xml:` is already declared together with the namespace URI `http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace`. You can think of it as

```
xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
```

but as an *implicit* declaration that is available in all XML documents, and recognized by all conformant XML applications.

Therefore, the answer to your question is: You do not need to declare the prefix `xml:` at all, it is available by default. You can use the [attributes in this namespace](http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace) (`xml:lang`, `xml:space`, `xml:base` and `xml:id`) without declaring their prefix.

By the way, you can try this yourself. Simply create an XML document without any namespace declarations and use `xml:lang` in it as an attribute:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xml:lang="en"/>
```

No XML processor will complain about it, not even your XSLT engine.